# Function supposed to dipslay time since date suddenly says its been 3 minutes on every timestamp

Tags: php

Escuse my for the title, my english is kind of limited.

Anyway I have this script on my site to take a unix timestamp and display how many seconds, minutes, dayrs or years its been since. Now suddently it says 3 minutes all over the place.

```
function humanTiming($time) 
{

$time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'm',
    604800 => 'w',
    86400 => 'd',
    3600 => 'h',
    60 => 'm',
    1 => 's'
);

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return $numberOfUnits.$text.' ago';
}

}
```

Result:

```
Posted 3m ago
```

This for example says 3 minutes:

```
echo humanTiming(1374929975);

(1374929975 = July 27th 2013 14:59)
```

Result

```
Posted 3m ago
```

Im pretty sure that wasnt 3 minutes ago.

Whats the problem? Does it work on your server? Please let me know

Comment: It works for me, exactly as posted.  If I do `humanTiming(time() - 7200)` I get `2h ago`

Comment: And `3m ago` for the Jul 27 time in your example.

Comment: See: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7zXmCO  If you have problems, it may more likely be with your output logic.